# Characterization of functions that are univariate on ellipses

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a function $g :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that  for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$
g(Ax)= g(x), \tag{$*$}
$$
for all orthogonal matricies $A$. Then $g(x)$ is only  a function of $\|x\|$.

In other words for all $x, y$ such that $x^Tx=y^Ty$ we have that $f(y)=f(x)$. That is the function has the same value on spheres of the same radius.

**My question:**     Suppose a function  $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has the same value on ellipses of the same radius can we find a condition similar to that in $(*)$ that characterizes this property of $f$.

More concretly, suppose that for some given symetric positive definite matrix $B$  the function $f$ satifies 
$$
f(x)=f(y), \ \forall   x^TBx=y^TBy. \tag{$**$}
$$
Can we find a condition similar or akin to the one in $(*)$ to test whether the function $f$ satisfies $(**)$.

Note that $x^TBx=c$ defines an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: you have it. Your new function depends only on $||x|| = \sqrt {x^T B x}$ I can add that, instead of orthogonal matrices $A,$ you are now using automorphism matrices $P,$ meaning $P^T B P = B.$

Comment: @WillJagy  But can we show that if for a set of matrices $f( Ax)=f(x)$ then $f(x)$ only depends on $\| x\| =\sqrt{x^T B x}$?  And what is this set of matrices?  In the case when $B=I$ the set is all orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, if for every $x$ and every matrix $P$ such that $P^T BP = B,$ we always have $f(Px) = f(x),$ then $f(x) $ depends only on $||x|| = \sqrt {x^T B x}.$ One of the main ingredients is the fact that, for symmetric positive definite $B,$ we can choose a fixed square $C$ with $C^T C = B,$ and use $C$ to relate the $B$ situation to the original one with orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @WillJagy  Yes, this is exactly the type of statement that I am looking for. Could you put this as an answer with a little more detailed proof? I am very interested how $C$ and $P$ relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to find a $C$ with $C^T C = B.$ One of these ways is called the Cholesky decomposition, so I use the letter $C.$

Now, we have $B = C^T C.$ Suppose we take an orthogonal matrix $A^T A = I.$ Next, for convenience of typing, define $$ D = C^{-1}. $$ Finally, define
$$ P = DAC.  $$
We calculate
$$  P^T BP = C^T A^T D^T C^TC DAC = C^T A^T I^T I A C = C^T A^T A C = C^T I C = C^T C = B $$

Next, given some $Q$ with $Q^T BQ = B,$ can you use $C,D$ to construct an orthogonal matrix using $Q \; ?$ You might try assuming that $Q = D WC$ with $W$ orthogonal and solve for $W,$ then check that $W$ really is orthogonal the way I did.

Comment: In this setting what is $P^TP$ equal to?

Comment: @Lisa nothing special, just as $A^T BA$ is nothing special. The collection of $P$ makes up a group; depending on the original language of the author, this is called the automorphism group of $B$ (or of the quadratic form defined by $B$), sometimes the rotation group of $B,$ or the isometry group, the orthogonal group of $B$

Comment: @Lisa do you know what the word "group" means in mathematics?

Comment: No unfortunately not. But I would like to learn. So if you can give me some beginners references.

Comment: @Lisa in that case, let me just say that if we have $P^TBP=B$ and $Q^T B Q = B,$ then $(PQ)^T B PQ = B$ and for that matter, $\left(P^{-1}\right)^T B P^{-1} = B.$ Also $I^T B I = B.$